# What is <!include = "/home/DBinfo.php"> at the top of an HTML page mean?

Tags: php, html

I'm studying database systems, and we are accessing the database using php on a webpage. This .php file has been given by the teacher for us to use to write basic php in. I tried googling "!include" but haven't been able to find an example like this one. I realize that another php file is being accessed, but I don't understand why it would be at the top of the page instead of within the php code itself. Could someone explain what is going on with the code below or point me to a website that explains it?

```
<!include = "/home/DBinfo.php">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very strange syntax due this manual about [phptags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php). There are these tags:

- standard choice `<?php` `?>`
- shorten tags `<?=`, `<?`
- asp tags `<%, %>, <%=, and the script tag <script language="php">` which was removed in php version `7.0.0`

But there exist webserver [`ssi includes`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html) with directive like `<!--#include virtual="/footer.html" -->` in some webservers (Apache, nginx, ...). But this command `<!include = "/home/DBinfo.php">` have different view.

Try to replace your code with this proper opening php tag and using [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) directive:

```
<?php include "/home/DBinfo.php";?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

This code should work in any normal environment.

Comment: And to answer the second part of the question, why is it at the top, is because it will literally take the entire included file and paste it in at the include location. So, if there is any PHP code that depends on the content of the include it has to come after the include. The easiest way to ensure that is by placing all includes at the top (plus it makes the file easier to reason about). You might one day have a case where you have multiple includes, and, just like adding JavaScript to your page, the order of the includes does actually matter.

Comment: @alex I'm going to say that the teacher has made an error here, even though the code is repeated in several files.